# How can I add a button on the bar at the bottom of the screen for Qt Nokia?

Tags: c++, qt, nokia

I am developing an application for my Nokia N8 running Nokia Belle and would like to add buttons in between the left arrow button and the menu button on the bar at the bottom of the screen.

An example of what I mean can be seen when playing a station in the Nokia Internet Radio application, which, I understand, is a Mobile Qt Widget Application (not Qt Quick).

After searching around (http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?233396-QMenu-in-Symbian-Belle-in-Qt-C), I tried this code, but the button does not appear:

```
QAction *pDeleteButton = new QAction(style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_TrashIcon),QString(tr("Delete")), this);
pDeleteButton->setSoftKeyRole(QAction::NoSoftKey);
addAction(pDeleteButton);
```

I put this code in the constructor of the mainwindow.cpp.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in programming for mobile phones, but the `QAction` you are creating has no parent widget. If you look at the example you are linking, you will find that the original poster assigned a menu for the action via `setMenu()`. Did you try something like this already? If so, I would suggest you add some more context to your code and maybe a minimal example.